# I am getting the items in Listview repeated . Here is my sample code I am unable to find the bug in my code ! Can anyone help me out please?

Tags: android

```
    //this is JOBListAdapter class

    package com.example.hellotest.adapters;

    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Locale;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.example.hellotest.R;
    import com.example.hellotest.model.Job;

    public class JobListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater ;
        private List<Job> mJobs;
        private SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat;
        private SimpleDateFormat mInputFormat;
        private String mPosterPrefix;

        public JobListAdapter(Context context) {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.US);
            mInputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.US);
            mPosterPrefix = context.getString(R.string.job_posted_by);
        }

        public void setJobList(List<Job> jobs) {
            mJobs = jobs;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            if(null != mJobs) {
                return mJobs.size();
            }
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mJobs.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return mJobs.get(position).getId();
        }
    //this is the method where I think that the problem is please somebody tell me.
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(null == convertView) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.job_list_row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.created = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.job_listing_date);
                holder.location = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.job_listing_location);
                holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.job_listing_title);
                holder.experience = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.job_listing_experience);
                holder.poster = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.job_listing_posted_by);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }



            updateRow(holder, mJobs.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }

        private void updateRow(ViewHolder holder, Job job) {
            holder.title.setText(job.getTitle());
            int id = job.isPremium() ? R.drawable.icon_premium : 0;
            holder.created.setText(getDate(job.getCreated()));
            holder.created.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, id, 0);
            holder.experience.setText(job.getExperience());
            holder.location.setText(job.getLocation());
            holder.poster.setText(mPosterPrefix + job.getPoster());
        }

        private CharSequence getDate(String created) {
            try {
                return mDateFormat.format(mInputFormat.parse(created));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return created;
        }

        private static class ViewHolder {
            TextView created;
            TextView title;
            TextView location;
            TextView experience;
            TextView poster;
        }

    }

   // layout for fragmentjob_listing even I make the listview height to fill_parent as suggested when      I googled the solution for the issue.

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/job_listing_filter_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/job_listing_tab_bg"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="48dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/job_listing_experience"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_job_listing_tab"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/job_listing_experience" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/space2"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/job_listing_horizontal_divider" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/job_listing_location"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_job_listing_tab"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/job_listing_location" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/job_listing_divider" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/job_listing_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/job_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

   // JobListingFragment Class where the joblistAdapter class called up

    package com.example.hellotest;

    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AbsListView;
    import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener;
    import com.android.volley.Response.Listener;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
    import com.example.hellotest.R;
    import com.example.hellotest.adapters.JobListAdapter;
    import com.example.hellotest.config.Constant;
    import com.example.hellotest.io.CookieStringRequest;
    import com.example.hellotest.io.json.JobsProcessor;
    import com.example.hellotest.model.Job;
    import com.example.hellotest.model.JobList;
    import com.example.hellotest.model.Pagination;
    import com.example.hellotest.tasks.JsonParserTask;
    import com.example.hellotest.tasks.JsonParsingListener;
    import com.example.hellotest.util.AccountUtils;
    import com.example.hellotest.util.Log;

    public class JobListingFragment extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_URL = "argument_url";
        public static final String ARG_IS_FILTER_ON = "argument_is_filtered";
        public static final String ARG_IS_DEFAULT_JOB_LIST = "argument_is_default_job_list";
        public static final String ARG_EMPTY_MESSAGE = "argument_empty_message";

        protected static final int REQUEST_EXPERIENCE = 0x11;
        protected static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 0x12;
        private ListView mJobsList;
        private TextView mMessageView;
        private JobListAdapter mAdapter;
        private List<Job> mJobs;
        private Pagination mPagination;
        private boolean mIsFetching;
        private boolean mIsDefaultList;
        private boolean mIsFilterOn;
        private String mUrl;
        private String mLocId;
        private int mExperienceId = -1;
        private ProgressBar mFooterProgress;
        private Log mLogger = new Log(JobListingFragment.class);
        private Object mRequestTag = new Object();
        private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mAdapter = new JobListAdapter(getActivity());
            if (null != savedInstanceState) {
                getState(savedInstanceState);
            } else {
                getState(getArguments());
            }
    //      init();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(mRequestTag);
            super.onDetach();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            init();
            super.onResume();
        }

        private void getState(Bundle bundle) {
            mUrl = bundle.getString(ARG_URL);
            mIsFilterOn = bundle.getBoolean(ARG_IS_FILTER_ON);
            mIsDefaultList = bundle.getBoolean(ARG_IS_DEFAULT_JOB_LIST);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_job_listing, null);
            mJobsList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.job_list);
            mMessageView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.job_listing_message);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View footer = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.paginated_list_footer, null);
            mFooterProgress = (ProgressBar) footer.findViewById(R.id.footer_progress);
            if (!mIsFilterOn) {
                view.findViewById(R.id.job_listing_filter_container).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                view.findViewById(R.id.job_listing_experience).setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
                view.findViewById(R.id.job_listing_location).setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
            }
            mJobsList.addFooterView(footer);
            mJobsList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mJobsList.setOnScrollListener(mOnScrollListener);
            mJobsList.setOnItemClickListener(mOnItemClickListener);
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            outState.putString(ARG_URL, mUrl);
            outState.putBoolean(ARG_IS_FILTER_ON, mIsFilterOn);
            outState.putBoolean(ARG_IS_DEFAULT_JOB_LIST, mIsDefaultList);
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

        public void startAfresh(String url, boolean isPaginated) {
            mLogger.d("old fragment reused");
            mIsFilterOn = true;
            mUrl = url;
            reset();
            init();
        }

        private void init() {
            mLocId = AccountUtils.getLocationFilter();
            mExperienceId = AccountUtils.getExperienceFilter();
            String url = getUrl(1);
            fetchJobs(url);

        }

        private void reset() {
            mJobs = null;
            mPagination = null;
            mAdapter.setJobList(null);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        private String getUrl(int pageNumber) {
            String appender = "";
            if (mIsFilterOn) {
                if (null != mLocId || -1 < mExperienceId) {
                    if (null != mLocId) {
                        appender += "/loc-" + mLocId;
                    } else {
                        appender += "/loc-" + 0;
                    }

                    if (-1 < mExperienceId) {
                        appender += "/exp-" + mExperienceId;
                    } else {
                        appender += "/exp-" + 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            String url = mUrl + appender + "/pg-" + pageNumber;
            if (mIsDefaultList && AccountUtils.isLoggedIn()) {
                url += "?" + Constant.MAP_COOKIE_KEY + "=" + AccountUtils.getCookie();
            }
            return url;
        }

        private void fetchJobs(String url) {
            mIsFetching = true;
            mLogger.d("url :" + url);
            int method = mIsDefaultList ? Method.GET : Method.POST;
            CookieStringRequest request = new CookieStringRequest(method, url, mListener, mErrorListener);
            request.setTag(mRequestTag);
            mRequestQueue.add(request);
        }

        private Response.Listener<String> mListener = new Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                mLogger.d("response :" + response);
                JsonParserTask<JobList> jsonTask = new JsonParserTask<JobList>(new JobsProcessor());
                jsonTask.setListener(mJsonListener);
                jsonTask.execute(response);

            }
        };

        private Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener = new ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                mIsFetching = false;
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.network_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };

        private JsonParsingListener<JobList> mJsonListener = new JsonParsingListener<JobList>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JobList result) {
                if (null == mPagination) {
                    mPagination = result.getPagination();
                    mPagination.setCurrentPage(0);
                    if(null == result.getJobs() || 0 == result.getJobs().size()) {
                        mMessageView.setText(getArguments().getString(ARG_EMPTY_MESSAGE));
                        mMessageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        mMessageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                } else {
                    mPagination.updateData(result.getPagination());
                }

                if (null != mJobs) {
                    mJobs.addAll(result.getJobs());
                } else {
                    mJobs = result.getJobs();
                }
                mAdapter.setJobList(mJobs);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mIsFetching = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to process response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mIsFetching = false;
            }
        };

        private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Job job = (Job) mAdapter.getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), JobDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(JobDetailsActivity.EXTRA_JOB, job);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
```

// this is the function where I also found that might cause some problem because when I scrolls down the items in the list repeated.
            private OnScrollListener mOnScrollListener = new OnScrollListener() {

```
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                boolean loadMore = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount;
                if (loadMore && totalItemCount > 0 && null != mPagination) {
                    boolean isLastPage = mPagination.getCurrentPage() >= mPagination.getTotalPages();
                    if (isLastPage) {
                        mFooterProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    if (!mIsFetching && !isLastPage) {
                        fetchJobs(getUrl(mPagination.getCurrentPage()+1));
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_EXPERIENCE:
                    onExperienceSelection(data);
                    break;

                case REQUEST_LOCATION:
                    onLocationSelection(data);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add one more line in your function:

```
mjob.clear();


private JsonParsingListener<JobList> mJsonListener = new JsonParsingListener<JobList>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JobList result) {
            if (null == mPagination) {
                mPagination = result.getPagination();
                mPagination.setCurrentPage(0);
                if(null == result.getJobs() || 0 == result.getJobs().size()) {
                    mMessageView.setText(getArguments().getString(ARG_EMPTY_MESSAGE));
                    mMessageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mMessageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            } else {
                mPagination.updateData(result.getPagination());
            }

            if (null != mJobs) {
                mJobs.clear();
                mJobs.addAll(result.getJobs());
            } else {
                mJobs = result.getJobs();
            }
            mAdapter.setJobList(mJobs);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mIsFetching = false;
        }
```

Comment: yes it is working fine but a new issue occurs that when i scrolls down the previous shown jobs are now not shown to user now. what i want that the previous jobs also shown  even if the list view scrols more.

Comment: Please provide me better option soon please

Comment: please help me out soon in fixing the bug

Comment: prshntjjl please see this issue as i have made in my comments 35 mins ago and help me out !!

Comment: for that you should take one scrollflag and when you scroll down your listview at that time you can check that flag and if it true then add values in listview OR clear and add..getting?

Comment: prshntjjl can you explain it with editing my existing code that will be great help Thanks

Comment: prshntjjl  I have done what you suggested me to do so if  i do:

if(!scrollFlag)
    {
     mJobs.clear();
     scrollFlag=false;
    
    mJobs.addAll(result.getJobs());}
then no more job feeds load if I do :

if(!scrollFlag)
    {
     mJobs.clear();
     scrollFlag=false;}
    
    mJobs.addAll(result.getJobs());

then the jobs again repeats

Comment: prshntjjl please help me to get rid of this bug..!

Comment: prshntjjl please see ahead on this almost solved please see and make me out of this bug thankyou

Comment: prshntjjl please  buddy its an important solve my issue first one please

Comment: visit this link which may help you to do pagination in your project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27289251/androidload-more-data-when-scroll-reaches-bottom/27289657#27289657