# Load more data when Scroll reaches bottom

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to Android. My requirement is to load extra data & set to the list view, when scroll reaches to the bottom. I am able to call next data but my previous data is hiding. How to correct this?

```
 listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                        int scrollState) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
                        int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                        int totalItemCount) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() == listView
                            .getAdapter().getCount() - 1
                            && listView.getChildAt(
                                    listView.getChildCount() - 1)
                                    .getBottom() <= listView
                                    .getHeight()) {
                        // scroll end reached

                        if (nextCall == null || nextCall == ""
                                || nextCall.equals("null")
                                || nextCall.equals("")) {

                        } else {

                            hostname=nextCall;

                            new ArticlesList().execute();

                        }

                        // Write your code here
                    }else{

                    }

                }
            });
            dialog.dismiss();
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Went wrong",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Comment: Consider using `ScrollView` instead of `ListView` and it's `onScrollChanged` method to identify when you reach the bottom of `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 3):

visit this which is discribe how to do pagination in listview. [PagingListView](https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/PagingListView)

Answer (score 1):

In listView adapter:

```
    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (position == items.size() - 1)
    {
        items.add("new data1");
        items.add("new data2");
        notificationDataSetChanged();
    }

    //inject your view here

}
```

You lose your data, because you are overwriting a link to it. You should add data, not replace it.

Comment: when i am trying like this (position == items.size() - 1),before reaching of scroll at bottom ,it is calling

Comment: @madhusudhan sry, i cant understand u( Please write with another words:)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an endless scroll Listener, please take a look at this: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews

just add this project to yours and use it like this:

```
yourListView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {

        ... your asynchTask
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(view, scrollState);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved the same problem using following code snippet.

private int lastVisibleItem; private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager; private int lastId; // get the last id of your post after first time load data from server. private int flag = 0;

linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

recyclerView_news.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

recyclerView_news.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int    newState){
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (list_news.size() - 1 == lastVisibleItem) {
                if (flag == 0) {
                    flag = 1;
                    getMoreData(lastId); // pass lastId to load next posts. 
                }
            } else if (list_news.size() - 1 != lastVisibleItem) {
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

});
Hope this will help. Thanks.